# What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?

Tags: video, codec, file-format, video-codecs

I'm so confused... what is the difference between an audio/video codec (which apparently is a shorthand for "encoder/decoder", kind of like how "modem" is really "modulator/demodulator") and an audio/video format?
(Am I even using the correct terminology?)

i.e.: What is the difference between saying something is "MPEG-4" and saying something uses the "DivX" codec? Why does Windows Media Player sometimes run `.mpg` files, and sometimes not?

Also, which of the following are codecs, which ones are file formats, and which ones are neither?

- Quicktime MOV
- MPEG (1, 2, 3, 4)
- WMV
- FFmpeg
- AVC
- Xvid
- DivX (how is it different from its palindrome, Xvid?)
- H.264

Comment: Looking at my own question 6 years later and all I can think is "how do you not know this?!"

Comment: We all started from somewhere. ;)

Comment: On the contrary - this is not really common knowledge, even now.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Some main definitions:

- A codec (e.g., H.264, HEVC, VP9) is only responsible for the video or audio part, and one or more codecs can be merged into a container.
- A container (e.g., MP4, MKV) is responsible for keeping them together and this is also what you usually open up in your media player of choice.
- A particular encoder (e.g., x264, libvpx) is responsible for turning an input stream into a codec-compliant bitstream. There are often multiple encoders for one particular codec.

[image]

As you can see, we'll have to explain a few things here.

## What is a codec?

A **codec** is short for encoder/decoder, which basically just means the following: Data generated by an encoder can always be decoded by an appropriate decoder. This happens to be valid for video, audio, but you could also think about cryptography (an encoder needs an appropriate decoder to display an encrypted message).

Nowadays, when a video codec is specified, the institutions that take part in it usually **only specify the syntax** of the standard. For example, they will say: "The bitstream format has to be like this", "The `0x810429AAB` here will be translated into that", etc. Often they supply a reference encoder and decoder, but how an encoder is then written to match such a format completely is up to manufacturers.

This is the reason why you will find so many encoders for the very same codec, and some of them even commercial.

### A case example – H.264

Before we mix up terminology, let's take an example. Consider the case for [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264). The standard's name is H.264 – that's not the name of the actual encoder. *Mainconcept* is a very good commercial encoder, whereas *x264* is a free and open source one. Both claim to deliver good quality, of course.

The mere fact that you can optimize encoding makes for a competition here. Both encoders will deliver a standardized bitstream that can always be decoded by a H.264-compliant decoder.

### To summarize

So, all in all, let's just say that an encoder will:

- take video frames
- produce a valid bitstream

The bitstream is then multiplexed into a container.

The decoder will:

- take that valid bitstream
- reconstruct the video frames from it

They both conform to a codec standard. That's all!

---

## Current Codecs

These days, you will probably only find videos encoded with the codecs I will mention below. Interestingly, almost *all* of them were created by the [Motion Picture Experts Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpeg) (MPEG). But there are some other, royalty-free codecs as well, e.g. those created by Google or the Alliance for Open Media, which are competitors to the MPEG standards.

Note that "MPEG" can refer to both codecs and containers, as you will see below. This adds to the confusion, but just know that "MPEG" alone doesn't mean anything, e.g. "I have a file in MPEG format" is *very* ambiguous".

#### [**MPEG-2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpeg-2)

MPEG-2 is quite old. Its first public release is from 1996. MPEG-2 video is mostly used for DVDs and TV broadcasting, e.g. DVB-T or satellite, and legacy applications where compatibility is important. MPEG-2 videos are mostly found in an *.MPG* container.

#### [**MPEG-4 Part 2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2)

This is probably the one that was used mostly to encode videos for the web in the mid-2000s, but it has been superseded in the meantime. It offers good quality at practical file sizes, which meant that you could burn a whole movie of 90 minutes length onto a 600 MB CD (whereas with MPEG-2 you would have needed a DVD, [see my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/299550/how-to-convert-any-video-to-dvd-vob-in-good-video-quality/299557#299557)). It doesn't work so well for HD or 4K content anymore.

Some encoders that output MPEG-4 Part 2 video are *DivX*, its open sourced ripoff *XviD*, and *Nero Digital*.

MPEG-4 Part 2 videos mostly come in an *AVI* container, but *MP4* is also seen often.

#### [**MPEG-4 Part 10 / AVC / H.264**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264)

This is also known as **MPEG-4 Advanced Video Coding (AVC)** or **H.264**; it is the most used codec today. It offers good quality at small file sizes and therefore is perfectly suited for all kinds of video for the Internet or mobile devices. You will find H.264 in almost every modern applications, from phones to camcorders. On Blu-ray disks, video is now encoded in H.264.

Some encoders for it are: *x264*, *NVENC* (from NVIDIA), *Mainconcept*. The videos mostly come in *MP4*, *MKV* or *MOV* containers.

#### [**HEVC / H.265**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEVC)

Also called MPEG-H Part 2, this is the successor of MPEG-4 Part 10 / AVC / H.264. It is aimed at higher resolutions (up to [8K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8K_UHDTV)) and can offer up to 50% higher encoding performance (in terms of quality vs. bitrate) compared to H.264 (see [this paper](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/180494/files/hanhart_SPIE2012_1.pdf), for example).

The standard was published in 2013, and slowly, the codec is beginning to be used more and more, e.g., for IPTV or online video transmissions. HEVC is also used by Apple to store videos and images (using [HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format)) on iOS. However, the fact that there are multiple patent pools associated with HEVC has many companies (almost all but Apple) shifting to royalty-free alternatives. HEVC is also [not natively supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) by all browsers, making it unusable for web streaming.

The best-known encoder is *x265*. There's also *NVENC*. The videos usually come in *MP4* containers.

#### [**VP9 and AV1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9)

[VP9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) (the successor of VP8) is a codec mainly developed by Google. It is open and royalty-free, and [implemented in many browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support). Its quality is almost as good as HEVC, and sometimes even better (see [this paper](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=2563030) by Netflix). VP9 is what you get when you watch YouTube on a browser that supports it.

VP9 can be encoded with the *libvpx* encoder, and it often comes in *WebM* or *MKV* containers.

Some companies got together to form an even stronger competitor to HEVC – but as a royalty-free alternative. [AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOMedia_Video_1) will be the successor of VP9, and it is based on what was supposed to become VP10. It is backed by the Alliance for Open Media (founded by Amazon, Cisco, Google, Intel, Microsoft, Mozilla, and Netflix). Read [more about it here](https://www.xda-developers.com/av1-future-video-codecs-google-hevc/).

The *libaom* encoder can be used to generate AV1 bitstreams, but it is still experimental.

---

## What is a format (container)?

Until now we've only explained the raw "bitstream", which is basically just really raw video data. You could actually go ahead and watch the video using such a raw bitstream. But in most cases that's just not enough or not practical.

Therefore, you need to wrap the video in a container. There are several reasons why:

- Maybe you want some audio along with the video
- Maybe you want to skip to a certain part in the video (like, "go to 1:32:20.12")
- Both audio and video should be perfectly synchronized
- The video might need to be transmitted over a reliable network and split into packets before
- The video might even be sent over a lossy network (like 3G) and split into packets before

For all of those reasons, container formats were invented, some simple, some more advanced. What they all do is "wrap" the video bitstream into another bitstream.

A container will synchronize video and audio frames according to their *Presentation Time Stamp* (PTS), which makes sure they are displayed at exactly the same time. It would also take care of adding information for streaming servers, if necessary, so that a streaming server knows when to send which part of the file.

Let's take a look at some popular containers.

---

### Popular containers

You will find videos mostly wrapped in the following containers. There are other less popular ones as well, but as I said, mostly, it's those:

#### [**AVI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave)

Audio Video Interleave — this is the most basic container, it's just there to interleave audio and video. It was written in 1992 and is still used today, but considered legacy, so do not use it anymore.

#### [**MP4**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp4)

is also known as **MPEG-4 Part 14** and is based on the QuickTime file format. This is the go-to format for H.264 video, but it also wraps HEVC, MPEG-4 Part 2 and MPEG-2.

This container might also wrap audio only, which is why you'll find so many .mp4 files which are no videos but rather [AAC-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) audio, also in .m4a files (just a different extension). The extension .m4v is usually taken for video bitstreams.

#### **[MKV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) and [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM)**

Matroska Video (MKV) is an open sourced and free file format that is often found  nowadays, as it supports basically any codec, from H.264 to VP9, and of course also many audio codecs.

WebM is based on MKV and is primarily used for VP9 video and Opus audio – it is the container of choice for web streaming video when these codecs are used.

#### [**Ogg**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg)

The Ogg container is the container of choice for the Theora video codec (and the Vorbis audio [codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis)), also created by the Xiph.Org Foundation. It's also free and open source (just like the codec).

#### [**FLV**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flv)

The Flash video format was created by Adobe, for use in their streaming applications. It isn't used that much anymore, as the way streaming is done has changed significantly over the last years.

---

### Popular codecs and formats

> Also, which of the following are codecs, which ones are file formats, and which ones are neither?

- **Quicktime MOV**: *.mov* is the file extension for the [QuickTime File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mov), which is a **container** created by Apple. This container was later adapted for MP4. It can carry all kinds of codecs. *Quicktime* is actually a whole media framework, it doesn't really specify any codec itself as far as I'm concerned.
- **MPEG (1, 2, 3, 4)**: Standards defined by the Motion Picture Experts Group. See my post above for details.
- **WMV**: Windows Media Video. It's actually a **codec** wrapped in an [Advanced Systems Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Systems_Format) container, which uses the *.wmv* extension again. Weird, but that's the way it is.
- **FFmpeg**: This is neither a codec nor a container. It is a library of video tools that also allow conversion between different codecs and containers. FFmpeg relies on the open source `libavcodec` and `libavformat` libraries for creating codecs and containers, respectively. Most of video tools you find today are based on it.
- **AVC**: Synonym for MPEG-4 Part 10 or H.264.
- **DivX**: Another type of encoder for MPEG-4 Part 2 video.
- **Xvid**: One type of encoder for MPEG-4 Part 2 video. It's just the open source, free version of DivX, which of course led to some controversy.
- **H.264**: Synonym for MPEG-4 Part 10 or AVC.

---

On a side note:

> Am I even using the correct terminology?

I guess once would prefer to specifically use "codec" and "container" instead of "format" to avoid misunderstandings. A format can theoretically be anything, because both codecs **and** containers specify a format (i.e. how data should be represented).

That being said, the [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) terminology would be to use "format" for the container. This is also because of the distinction between:

- `libavcodec`, the library for encoding/decoding
- `libavformat`, the library for the containers

Comment: Now, that's what one can rightly call answering a question. Well done.

Comment: Great answer, but you missed the Ogg container format.

Comment: This is the most awesome answer I've seen in a while. Thanks a lot for the great explanations! :)

Comment: @Mehrdad Glad I could shed some light onto the subject. Thank you :)

Comment: Nice! I wonder if flv is also a kind of container? What do you think of it, good or not, as compared to your favourite mp4 and mkv?

Comment: @Tim It's not a bad container format, but support for FLV in playback devices is limited. Consider storing tons of videos in FLV, and then finding out your NAS doesn't stream them to your TV, or your iPod doesn't play them natively, etc. MP4 is the most commonly accepted aside from AVI.

Comment: @slhck this is a truly awesome answer. The only thing missing is an explanation of mpeg ttransport streams.

Comment: @evilsoup Thank you! I know, I left out MPEG-2 PS/TS – but I figured they weren't as relevant to typical consumers. Feel free to add a paragraph similar to the others if you like – you're always welcome to suggest an edit.

Comment: @slhck yeah, they don't really have many uses for the average user: concatenating videos with ffmpeg, and I guess using them for streaming... neither of which are typical consumer needs; but it's possible that users will come across them while recording off of TV capture cards, and while blu-ray ripping, so a brief explanation could be useful, just to avoid confusion. I'll suggest an edit soon.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning codecs used for different purposes. For example ProRes which is used in post production for its speed and high-bit depth with minimal lossy compression, or FFV1 and JPEG2K which are used for lossless high quality archival purposes, but all of which would be rubbish for sending video over the internet. And a mention of audio codecs might be good too.

Comment: @stib That's of course good to know, but definitely beyond the scope of typical consumer-oriented codecs. I highly doubt somebody who doesn't already work in video production will need ProRes. Also, this answer is already a *bit* long :)

Comment: @slhck Why are they called codecs and not modems?

Comment: @sunk818 Because a modem modulates information as signals onto a carrier signal, much like your FM radio does. A codec does not do that, but instead transforms the signal into another domain.

Comment: Sometimes you wish you could do multiple upvotes on an answer :)

Comment: Also worth noting: 1) mp4 with only audio sometimes use the `.m4a` extension. 2) Some WMV files *do* use an `.asf` extension for the Advanced System Format container.

Comment: Ouch! No! No! No! Flash (FLV) was created by Macromedia and bought by Adobe so they could integrate the functionality in their PDF utilities. Adobe has maintained it but since HTML5 came out, Flash pretty disappeared.

Comment: I just created my Superuser account to upvote this answer as it was as awesome as it could get

Answer (score 3):

In general a media 'format' is really a container, containing an audio stream (of some audio codec) and a video stream (of some video codec) and sometimes additional information. most 'files' you have have a filetype based on container and not codec

FFmpeg is neither a container nor a codec - its a versatile suite of libraries, codecs and software for conversion of files that underlies many converters and music players.

H.264/AVC and xvid/divx are codecs

AVI (which divx/xvid files are), mp4, mpeg are containers.

I'm not sure about quicktime mov - .mov is a container, quicktime is a codec.

Comment: There is no "Quicktime" codec. Quicktime is a multimedia framework, including the .mov container, software for encoding, decoding and displaying a range of codecs, as well as other curiosities like Quicktime VR.

Answer (score 1):

there are [codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec)s and [containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) (file formats).  The codec describes how the data is encoded/decoded.  The other describes how the encoded data is placed inside the file.

Most media players support multiple codec and container types.  This is confusing, so I suggest you read my references for more informstion

Answer (score -1):

A format is the name given to a particular file format type and compression type (most video is compressed to keep the size down), and the codec is what can actually compress it, read it and translate it into the video you see by decompressing it. In other words, one is a file type, but the other is a piece of software.

We usually refer to most video by the format name, so Quicktime MOV, MPEG, and WMV are formats.

FFmpeg (I had never heard of this) appears to be the name of a software to convert various formats into other formats.

AVC and H.264 are the same, and are a format for encoding HD video.

DivX is a commercially sold codec.

Xvid is a codec for MPEG-4.

Comment: ffmpeg is pretty much the backend for 99% of FOSS converters.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Out of 7 sentences only numbers 6 and 7 are correct, even those lack detail.