# MP4 and FLV formats, which one is smaller for the same video?

Tags: video, mp4, flv

Is an MP4 file for a video smaller or larger than that of a FLV format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MP4 and FLV are just *container* formats.  The size of the container depends on the content within it, which can use an arbitrary compression format (depending on the compression format supported by the MP4 and FLV containers).

You need to compare the compression format of the file, *not* the container.

Even if you were to compare the relative compression rates of different video encoders, it also depends on bitrate, colour depth, framerate, resolution, and *much* more.  **In general**, however, the use of H.264 often results in relatively good quality with low filesizes - and is supported in *both* .MP4 and .FLV files.

Comment: so depending on compression formats, in one instance a flv file could be smaller where as for some other file, it could be larger?

Comment: Exactly.  The FLV is just the *container* (think of it as holding each stream in the file, since video and audio are two separate streams), it says nothing about what the video itself is (or the quality, size, etc...).  The container basically glues the individual streams together (so some containers can have multiple audio streams, for example to have different languages).

Comment: @Gunner If you want to, you can read up on that here: [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](http://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mpg/300997#300997)