# No video shown in MOV files when played in VLC on Linux

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, quicktime

Files with the .MOV extension are great with their tiny size!

I'm trying to play these files on Linux using VLC, as it's a great cross-platform application, but the problem is that NO video is shown while the audio is playing.

How can I solve this problem and enjoy watching MOV files?

Here is file media info:
[image]

Comment: More info needed: Does this happen for *any* file with the MOV container (note that the tiny size comes from the video codec inside this container, not the MOV container itself)? Do these files work in any other media player? Does VLC show any error message? What does it show about the file's information (e.g. the contained streams)?

Comment: Hmm....I've tried alternative players,on Windows OS VLC gives same problem but Kmplayer plays files without any problem !On Linux tried Parole which can plays Video not Audio unlike VLC does :(...any suggestion ?

Comment: Parole plays video, but no audio? Please add the [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) output to your question, that might help.

Comment: Yes,Parole does, MediaInfo trying to install it !

Comment: Info added,any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, judging from MediaInfo, the video codec is 1000 frames per second and `smc` This is the Apple Graphics Codec, a proprietary codec that probably isn't supported in every player.

[See also](http://multimedia.cx/smc.txt):

> The SMC codec is identified in Quicktime files by the codec FOURCC
>   "smc " (note the space, ASCII 0x20, needed to complete the
>   four-character code). Ostensibly, the codec was named after its developer,
>   Sean M. Callahan.

The audio codec is [QCELP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_code-excited_linear_prediction), a proprietary codec by Qualcomm.

---

I'm afraid these are very specialized codecs, and therefore you can't expect every player to support them. While VLC [claims to support SMC](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Features_Formats#Rarer_Video_Codecs), you've obviously encountered a bug. Therefore, you could use these files and file a bug report with the VLC developer team.

In any case you can try using FFmpeg to re-encode the file to a more widely used video codec such as h.264 (`libx264` in FFmpeg) or MPEG-4 (`mpeg4`). See here for more: [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/)

Comment: thnx,I did a report to VLC team hope to fix it as fast as they can,A question:To which extension can I re-ecncode these files keeping size acceptable ?

Comment: The extension itself doesn't really matter. The codec is important (as I said, h.264 or MPEG-4). You can use `.mp4` or `.mkv` as extensions — these are the most widely used today. Don't use `.avi`, it's really old :) See also: [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](http://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp)

Answer (score -1):

I got the .mov video to work in mpc-hc build number 1.6.1.4074:

- Go to View → Options
- Go to Player → Formats
- In the "Formats" window, find "Quick Time Movie (mov)" on the right
- Double-click on the dropdown on right side and select "QuickTime"
- Done

Comment: This questions concerns the Linux OS