# How to convert an MKV video to DivX format

Tags: video, video-conversion, matroska, divx

I have a file in an MKV format and I want to convert it to a DivX format.

Are there any tools out there which explain how to do this? I am fine doing a little coding on my own. I did try out the [DIVX convertor](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/converter)  but that only converts to an MKV format.

Any other options which are open to me right now?

Comment: See the blog [post](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) on using FFmpeg, otherwise use WinFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little misunderstanding here.

- *MKV* (Matroska) is a *container*. It wraps a number of video, audio and subtitle streams into one file.
- *DivX* is a *video encoder*. It's one implementation of a certain video *codec*.
- *MPEG-4 Part II* is a *video codec* standard. DivX for example creates MPEG-4 Part II compatible video. XviD is another encoder that does this.

See this question for more about that: [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](https://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp/300997#300997)

Now that we've cleared that up, there's not much sense anymore in "converting MKV to DivX". In fact, the MKV file you have could already include DivX-encoded video – who knows? You can analyze existing files with [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to make sure.

So, you seem to be unsure about what result you even want. DivX-encoded files can come in a number of containers, but AVI, MP4 and MKV are most common. If you want to create a DivX-encoded file, then you have to live with the fact that it will end up in an AVI, MP4 or MKV container, no matter what tool you use.

Comment: Okay that does seem to clear up a lot of things. So does it mean that a file cannot have an extension of divx as divx is a codec and not a container? or does it mean a file with a .divx extension is a raw bitstream ? Or have I made some gross error here? Also what would be the right site to read up on containers and codecs (any specific books which you recommend. Cause I am interested in learning about this but am unsure about where to start?)

Comment: Well, actually there *is* a .divx extension, but in essence it's an AVI container. [See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DivX#DivX_Media_Format_.28DMF.29). I haven't seen this a lot, but I would assume only official DivX products can create these files.

Comment: For the whole concepts of codecs and containers, I can't recommend any specific books though — I tried to be as extensive as possible in my answer ("What is a codec…"), but of course, there's always more to that. Feel free to read my two [blog posts on video encoding](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/11/07/video-conversion-done-right-codecs-and-software/) and [FFmpeg specifically](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/). And of course, you can ask a specific question anytime here on Super User.

Comment: Finally, there's [videohelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/), a place for how-tos, guides and articles on video encoding stuff. It also hosts the most commonly used tools you need for encoding, manipulating and the likes.

Comment: Okay. IF there is a .divx format then how do i create it because when i used the official divx convert it gave me an mkv which was divx encoded. Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe you need to buy one of "DivX Plus Pro" products if you really need .divx files. It's mentioned in [the feature list](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/pro) (scroll down).

Comment: Okay. I completely missed that but anyway,just  one last question(sorry for asking so many) but if a player is supposed to support divx, doesnt it mean that that an mkv container containing a divx encoded video should also be supported?

Comment: If a player claims to support DivX, I guess that rather means the codec. But they could also mean the file format. It really depends. And no, the MKV format has to be explicitly supported as well, even if the DivX codec inside was supported, some players might not support MKV out of the box. Can you maybe explain what player we're talking about or what your higher goals are? Maybe I can help you better then.

Comment: Yea sure. But first i have to accept your asnswer. Now that out of the way I have a c370xtl DVD player.http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/tv-audio-video/dvd-player/standard-dvd-player/DVD-C370/XTL. It says it supports DIvx , but a divx encoded MKV container does not play.

Comment: Yes, that is because these players can't read MKV. When they say they support DivX, this mostly means you can play *any* MPEG-4 Part II encoded video (i.e. not only DivX, but also XviD), and they have to be in an AVI container.

Comment: Okay.Let me try to convert the container to avi and get back to you.