# Media Information for Constant and Variable bit rate of Video files

Tags: windows, video, bitrate, media-info

What is this *Maximum bit rate* for a `.mp4` format file whose bit rate mode is **Constant**?

Media information displayed for MP4 (Using MediaInfo Tool)

`ID : 1`
`Format : AVC`
`Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec`
`Format profile : Baseline@L3.0`
`Format settings, CABAC : No`
`Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frame`
`Codec ID : avc1`
`Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding`
**`Bit rate mode : Constant`**
`Bit rate : 1 500 Kbps`
**`Maximum bit rate : 3 961 Kbps`**
`Display aspect ratio : 4:3`
`Frame rate mode : Constant`
`Frame rate : 29.970 fps`
`Color space : YUV`
`Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0`
`Bit depth : 8 bits`
`Scan type : Progressive`
`Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.163`

---

In this case where the bit rate mode is set to **Variable**, is the Bit rate field where the value is displayed as `309` is its average bit rate?

Media information displayed for M4V (Using MediaInfo Tool)

`ID : 1`
`Format : AVC`
`Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec`
`Format profile : Baseline@L3.0`
`Format settings, CABAC : No`
`Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frame`
`Codec ID : avc1`
`Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding`
**`Bit rate mode : Variable`**
`Bit rate : 309 Kbps`
`Display aspect ratio : 16:9`
`Frame rate mode : Variable`
`Frame rate : 23.976 fps`
`Minimum frame rate : 23.810 fps`
`Maximum frame rate : 24.390 fps`
`Color space : YUV`
`Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0`
`Bit depth : 8 bits`
`Scan type : Progressive`
`Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.229`
`Writing library : x264 core 120`

Answer (score 3):

When MediaInfo reports `Bit rate`, it'll report the bit rate the actual media stream specifies. So, if it says 1,500 and a constant bit rate was used, then this is the rate that was set by the encoder.

On the other hand, when a variable bit rate mode was used for encoding, the encoder cannot supply you with a predefined average. So, MediaInfo will report the measured average. It does that by analyzing the stream size and the duration (see `File__Analyze_Streams_Finish.cpp` in its source code), in a very generic fashion.

When it gives you a `Maximum bit rate` for VBR, the meaning is pretty evident. It also reports `Maximum bit rate` in the case of CBR streams.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find out what it means exactly—the source code is a little convoluted—but it depends on the specific media codecs or containers used.

Could be one of these:

- the result of a calculation, searching for a peak bit rate (very unlikely, haven't checked the full source code)
- a piece of information extracted from the [MOOV atom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html) of the MP4 container
- the MPEG-2 descriptor defined in [ISO/IEC 13818-1](http://mumudvb.braice.net/mumudrupal/sites/default/files/iso13818-1.pdf) section 2.6.26:

  > The value indicates an upper
  > bound of the bitrate, including transport overhead, that will be encountered in this program element or program
- the maximum bit rate supported by  a certain container, e.g. in MXF
- the maximum bit rate supported by a certain codec profile / level combination

---

By the way: The MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14) container has no restrictions on bit rates of the codecs used as far as I know. [MP4 is not a video codec](https://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp/300997#300997). If you're talking about "MP4" as in MPEG-4 Part 10 AVC video (h.264), then the maximum bit rate specified by the High 10 profile at level 5.2 is 720,000 kBit/s ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264#Levels)).