# How can I get my MKV files to play on a PS3?

Tags: video-conversion, playstation

I just finished building a video server for PS3 and I am working on converting all of my DVD and Blu-ray to my HDD.

For DVD, MP4 files work great, but the PS3 can't play MKV which is what I use for my Blu-ray rips and such.

What format can I rip my Blu-ray to that will be full HD and still be playable on a PS3?  I only need 2.1 audio.

Comment: This question is not off topic for Super User. It's not about operating a game console, it's about using your computer to rip videos from Blu-ray discs or convert them.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are the video bitstream in your MKV container is one that the MP4 container can handle as well, which would be MPEG-4 Part II or H.264 video. It depends on the tool you're using to rip the Blu-rays, but the codec will probably be H.264.

Already confused? See:

- [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](https://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp)
- [Comparison of container formats - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats)

In essence, you can copy the video, audio and subtitle bitstreams from the MKV to the MP4 container and play that on the PS3. For example with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy out.mp4
```

The benefit is that this will take less than a second because it won't re-encode the video or audio. So you won't even lose quality in the process.

A combination of [mkvtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) and [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box) should give you similar results.

With that being said you could simply do your Blu-ray rips in MP4 in the future—unless there's something the MKV container gives you which MP4 doesn't, maybe with regard to subtitles. If your FFmpeg command fails due to an improper subtitle codec, use the following instead, which will re-encode subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s mov_text out.mp4
```

Comment: Lol.  I do know about codecs and containers, but thank you for the very detailed answer.  All of my personal MKVs are h264 and they have ac3 audio.  I already use ffmpeg for audio all the time, I didn't know that it supports video too.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, great then! MP4 should support AC-3 audio as well, so you should be good to go. Let me know if you encounter any issues.

Answer (score 4):

If you can jailbreak your PS3, then do that, and install the superb app called as `Showtime`. It's basically VLC for PS3.

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 can only read MP4 container format, not your MKV files. The easiest tool to convert MKV to MP4 without losing any quality is [YAMB](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/audio_video/convert_video/yamb.cfm). YAMB will not transcode the audio or video, so each movie will only take a few minutes.

1. Download YAMB from [here](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/audio_video/convert_video/yamb.cfm)
2. In YAMB, create MP4
3. Add you MKV file
4. Set Output name
5. Create