# error in convert video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg failed to transcode dsmall.mp4.
Reported errors

```
PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "/var/www/vhosts/imodb.ir/cinemagram.ir/sites/default/files/videos/original/dsmall_5.mp4" as FFmpeg returned an error. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".
```

Executed commands and output

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/var/www/vhosts/imodb.ir/cinemagram.ir/sites/default/files/videos/original/dsmall_5.mp4' -vf 'scale=498:360' -strict experimental -vcodec 'libx264' -acodec 'alac' -ac '2' -pass '1' -passlogfile '/tmp/1408770806-53f822f6bbf29-multipass'  -y /tmp/1408770806-53f822f6bbe41.mp4

FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 14 2014 22:54:14 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --enable-libfaac --enable-shared --enable-memalign-hack --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-swscale
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/vhosts/imodb.ir/cinemagram.ir/sites/default/files/videos/original/dsmall_5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 83 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
[buffer @ 0xb13d80] w:560 h:320 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0xb142f0] w:560 h:320 fmt:yuv420p -> w:498 h:360 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
[libx264 @ 0xa62cd0] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0xa62cd0] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0xa62cd0] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0xa62cd0] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0xa62cd0] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1408770806-53f822f6bbe41.mp4':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 498x360, q=2-31, pass 1, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: alac, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

**update**
we install new version of `ffmpeg` with below properties

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandi
r=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enabl
e-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11gra
b --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-
libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopenco
re-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enab
le-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx2
64 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_F
ORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -m
tune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

**I want to convert every video to `mp4` , what is good preset for my goal ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error is that your original video only has mono audio whereas you're requesting two channels for output.

But then again, you're using a terribly outdated version of `ffmpeg`. It's so ancient that the FFmpeg project doesn't even use SVN anymore – that was 2011. The old version might have bugs that prevent it from running the command.

You should [download a newer one](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (one of the static builds) and use that instead, or even [compile it yourself](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide). Newer versions have thousands of bugs fixed, have more sensible default behavior and give you more meaningful errors if something happens.

Since you seem to be using PHPVideoToolkit, which is *also* outdated, consider switching to [phpvideotoolkit-v2](https://github.com/buggedcom/phpvideotoolkit-v2) which at least supports ffmpeg 1.2. Current ffmpeg is 2.3 though. Or you use [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/), which also seems to be actively developed.

---

Regarding your command line, I presume you don't want `alac` as audio codec, but `aac`. ALAC is Apple's Lossless Audio Codec, whereas for H.264 video you typically want AAC audio. Change it to `-acodec aac` (or with newer syntax, `-c:a aac`). This is something the PHP frameworks will do for you automatically if you choose the right settings, of course.

Comment: Is that mean old version ?`FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 14 2014 22:54:14 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)` ?

Comment: See the "Copyright 2011"? That version was released more than three years ago.

Comment: you right, thank you very much, I try you solution

Comment: @zhilevan I just checked again.. I'm pretty sure you don't want `alac` as audio codec, but `aac`. Is that correct? ALAC is Apple's Lossless Audio Codec, whereas for H.264 video you typically want AAC audio.

Comment: tnx for you attention, I update my question, please update your anwer , tnx

Comment: If you simply want a video for HTML5, check http://superuser.com/questions/750811/convert-avi-into-h-264-that-works-inside-an-html5-video-tag/750815#750815