# FFMPEG Lossless Video Output Options

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.264, video-encoding, lossless

I am looking for lossless video output options from FFMPEG that can be viewed without any special codecs or special players such as VLC. I want a basic use to be able to open up the video with a player such as Windows Media Player.

I am currently have the following options:

Creating a raw video output video in an avi container:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f avi -c:v rawvideo output.avi
```

Creating a Huffyuv output video in an avi container (Proper playback in WMP but not in VLC. Strange.):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f avi -c:v huffyuv output.avi
```

Creating a h264 video in an avi container (Video does not playback properly in WMP):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 -qc 0 output.avi
```

I am open to any suggestions. I want to decrease file size while maintaining no loss of information from the source and allow easy playback on a standard windows install.

**Update:** Both huffyuv and libx264 work in VLC 2.2.0. I am still looking for a solution that doesnt involve VLC if possible.

Comment: Windows Media Player + good quality and easy playback on a standard Windows install is practically impossible. Windows has terrible codec support. When you want it lossless, even more so. What versions of Windows (Media Player) are you targeting?

Comment: I am not really targeting one version. End users are using windows computers and are likely on either Windows Vista or 7.

Comment: Actually, HuffYUV should work in VLC. Are you using a recent version?

Comment: VLC is 2.1.5. Current is 2.2.0.
I tested the windows wildlife video and it played back properly. My test file does not play back properly: ffmpeg -i test.avi -f avi -c:v huffyuv testoutput.avi My input file is as follows:
Input #0, avi, from 'test.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.11.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 233 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 704x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 22
:15], 237 kb/s, 3 fps, 3 tbr, 3 tbn, 3 tbc

Comment: Upgraded to 2.2.0 and huffYUV and libx264 work... strange.

Comment: Did you find how to use Lossless video in FFMPEG?

Comment: After some limited research and lots of trying, here's what ended up working for me: ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p render.mp4 . The -crf 0 arguments sets libx264 to lossless. This answer helped: https://superuser.com/a/750815/155017